# PHP spl_autoload practise with static functions

Tags: php, autoload, spl

I'm using an autoload for my classes such as:

```
function my_autoloader($Class){
  // classes
  include "class/Class_User.php";

  // helpers
  include "helper/Url_Helper.php";

  }

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

All is working great however I have some question. The content of Url_Helper is not a class, there are just a classic php functions I use across the site. The functions in Url_Helper are accessible only AFTER I initiate some (any) class like: $User = new User();

After this the functions get loaded. But if I call a function from Url_Helper and do not use any class at all it doesn't get loaded.

Can you explain me a little bit what's going on in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already debugged it. You say when you load no class, the helpers don't get loaded; this is true. If you want your helpers always to be available, you should include them outside of your autoload function.

Comment: Meaning that the spl_autoload should not contain classic php functions? I mean - its strange that they get loaded eventually if I use any class..

Comment: Not really, that's what an autoloader does. Whenever you call upon a class and it's not there yet, it will use the autoloader. So everything you put in there, will only be called the first time you use a new class.

Comment: So basically what I need (or should?) to do is to put the include of those function outside of autoload? I mean I like the way it is in autoload function :)

Comment: You're not using your autoloader properly anyway. Or at least not for what it was intended. Read up on this: http://www.codeforest.net/autoload-your-classes-in-php